# android media player notification

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have coded up a media player which streams MP3 from a website.

With a media player such as Winamp, I can go check my email or Facebook while its playing and then go back to win-amp by using the notification window. I wanted to know if I can do something like that with my media player.

I have looked at: [Android Media Player Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188170/android-media-player-threading) ,[Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and many more.

I goggled this concept and found a lot of confusing topics. Some people made a service while some make a foreground service and then added notification to that. I am confused on how I can make this possible. If someone can explain this concept (going from my activity class to notification bar) to me, I will be grateful. Sample code will be greatly appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question and decided to share with fellow novice users/students who are learning android development.

Basically, you have to use a service side by side with your activity class if you want an effective media player. After making the service, you have to make it into a foreground service which will help you make your media player into a notification.

If I am incorrect then please correct me. Thank you

Sample code: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm

Comment: here as you wrote that we need to update for ground service also. then provide that example link also. that will be your full answer.